# what will translate function do if I want to change some chars to nothing?

Tags: oracle, translate

I have a sql statement:

```
select translate('abcdefg', 'abc', '') from dual;
```

Why the result is nothing?
I think it should be 'defg'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm):

> You cannot use an empty string for *to_string* to remove all characters in *from_string* from the return value. Oracle Database interprets the empty string as null, and if this function has a null argument, then it returns null. To remove all characters in from_string, concatenate another character to the beginning of *from_string* and specify this character as the *to_string*. For example, `TRANSLATE(expr, 'x0123456789', 'x')` removes all digits from *expr*.

So you can do something like:

```
select translate('abcdefg', '#abc', '#') from dual;

TRANSLATE('ABCDEFG','#ABC','#')
-------------------------------
defg
```

... using any character that isn't going to be in your `from_string`.

Comment: @Alex, +1 for the quote from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> select translate('abcdefg', 'abc', '') from dual;

To add to Alex's answer, you could use any character(allowed in SQL) for that matter to concatenate to remove all the characters. So, you could even use a `space` instead of `empty string`. An empty string in Oracle is considered as `NULL` value.

So, you could also do -

```
SQL> SELECT TRANSLATE('abcdefg', ' abc', ' ') FROM dual;

TRAN
----
defg

SQL>
```

Which is the same as -

```
SQL> SELECT TRANSLATE('abcdefg', chr(32)||'abc', chr(32)) FROM dual;

TRAN
----
defg

SQL>
```

Since the `ascii` value of space is 32.

It was just a demo, it is better to use any other character than space for better understanding and code readability.